# Automating remote software updates in Adobe Flash application (.exe)

Tags: flash

I have a desktop flash application (.exe).
Is there a way to automatically update the client's software to the last version?

Answer (score 1):

use Adobe Air, the update system is integrated and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert your application using [Flajector](http://www.flajector.com/).
In this case, you will not have to worry about versions of Flash.

Comment: are you sure that you can use flajector in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I created an auto update example a few years ago. It's AS2 but it works and should be easy to upgrade to AS3. You can find it over here http://www.northcode.com/forums/showpost.php?p=42316&postcount=32. Full source is included. You'll need SWF Studio to make it work.